# Revealing SVG animation on HORIZONTAL scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm a little perplexed as to how I can fix my problem.

Just to start off, here's the website page link I have the issue with: http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/#horizontal/1

At first glance, there isn't any issues - however what I'm wanting to do is simply do what the Wow.js plugin does but horizontally, not vertically. This being to reveal content and do the (in this case) SVG animation when you enter that tab or 'viewport'. As you can see my website works similarly to a slideshow... However when I try implement plugins like Wow.js they won't work because they're not your standard vertical website.

The time may be somewhat of a factor, it's rather late at night so my brain is cloudy - but do any of you have any ideas as to how I can implement this idea?

Bear in mind, my knowledge of JS is limited - hence why I jumped for the plugin...

Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to understand javascript code, then you should consider forking wow.js plugin and change the source code as per your requirement but if you are not then there is another plugin which I used to build a site. The plugin is http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/. You can use this plugin and have vertical as well as horizontal animations in your website.

Comment: I did. I don't think you went through the link I suggested. you would have received your answer in how that plugin works and how it is a solution for your problem.

Comment: If you look on my website you will realise a couple of things - one, I'm using full page. Two full page doesn't do what I need it to